# How to use Modulus Operator with other data types?

Tags: c++, floating-point, modulus

i am trying to use Modulus Operator with float.
can anyone tell me how can use Modulus Operator with float or double data type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    float x = 100.23;
    cout<<"yes "<<x%2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:23: error: invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator%’
    cout<<"yes "<<x%y<<endl;
```

Comment: You might be looking for the [fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function.

Comment: could you please elaborate it ....

Comment: The `%` operator is defined for integers only. For floats, you have fmod.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is defined for integers only. For floats, you have the [fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function.

Comment: @Deepanshu Mehta - You can accept this answer, thanks!